# Convert AdWords XML File to C# List

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This is my XML File

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<report>
<report-name name='XML report: Account-Performance this month'/>
<date-range date='Sep 1, 2018-Sep 18, 2018'/>
    <table>
        <columns>
            <column name='impressions' display='Impressions'/>
            <column name='clicks' display='Clicks'/>
            <column name='ctr' display='CTR'/>
            <column name='conversions' display='Conversions'/>
            <column name='convRate' display='Conv. rate'/>
            <column name='costConv' display='Cost / conv.'/>
            <column name='avgCPC' display='Avg. CPC'/>
            <column name='cost' display='Cost'/>
        </columns>
        <row impressions='19534' clicks='876' ctr='4.48%' conversions='17.00' convRate='1.94%' costConv='52278824' avgCPC='1014543' cost='888740000'/>
    </table>
</report>
```

This file gets generated over the AdWords API. I am now trying to convert this xml File into a c# list. This is my approach so far:

```
// generate list out of xml
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var reports = xmlDoc.Elements();
foreach (var report in reports)
{
    var row = report.Element("row");
}
```

Unfortunately var row is null. I did some debugging and there is exactly one report in "reports" so there must be something wrong with the last part.

Comment: This doesnt validate as well formed xml

Comment: apart from the missing Table node, It should be `Elements("row")` instead of Element("row")`. The table can have multiple rows.

Comment: The xml file gets generated by the adwords api. I cannot change the structure or anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is searching for `report`'s first child element which is called `row`, but you want `table`'s first `row` element.

To get the `row` element, you have to change your code to this:

```
foreach (var report in reports)
{
    var row = report.Element("table").Element("row");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at wrong place. If your XML is correct it will be like

```
string dataXML = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<report>
    <report-name name='XML report: Account-Performance this month'/>
    <date-range date='Sep 1, 2018-Sep 18, 2018'/>
    <table>
        <columns>
            <column name='impressions' display='Impressions'/>
            <column name='clicks' display='Clicks'/>
            <column name='ctr' display='CTR'/>
            <column name='conversions' display='Conversions'/>
            <column name='convRate' display='Conv. rate'/>
            <column name='costConv' display='Cost / conv.'/>
            <column name='avgCPC' display='Avg. CPC'/>
            <column name='cost' display='Cost'/>
        </columns>
        <row impressions='19534' clicks='876' ctr='4.48%' conversions='17.00' convRate='1.94%' costConv='52278824' avgCPC='1014543' cost='888740000'/>
    </table>    
</report>";
```

If your XML has multiple reports

```
XDocument xmldx = XDocument.Parse(dataXML);
var myReport = xmldx.Elements("report");
foreach (var report in myReport)
{
    var row = report.Element("table").Element("row");
}
```

If your table has multiple rows

```
XDocument xmldx = XDocument.Parse(dataXML);
var myReport = xmldx.Element("report");
foreach (var table in myReport.Elements("table"))
{
    var row = table.Element("row");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way will be to travel the element step by step: Report>Table>Row.
You were missing the Table node.

```
var result = xmlDoc
    .Element("report")
    .Element("table")
    .Elements("row")
    .Select(r => new //my customObject here
    {
        impressions = (int)r.Attribute("impressions"),
        clicks = (int)r.Attribute("clicks"),
        ctr = (string)r.Attribute("ctr")
    });
```

If you were looking for all rows no matter where they are

```
var result2 = xmlDoc
            .Descendants("row")
            .Select(r => new
            {
                impressions = (int)r.Attribute("impressions"),
                clicks = (int)r.Attribute("clicks"),
                ctr = (string)r.Attribute("ctr")
            });
```

Note that even if your Xml show only one row, I handeled it as a table can has multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify where in the document your `row` elements are. In this case it's simple and robust to use `XPathSelectElements`:

```
// generate list out of xml
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var rows = xmlDoc.Root.XPathSelectElements("/report/table/row");
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    // ...
}
```

You may need to experiment with the XPath query, but I think that one should work for you.